# Coarea formula and its application

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I have a question about coarea formula.

Last day, I found the following assertion in a paper:

"Since $f \in C(\bar{D})$ and $D$ is a bounded $C^1$-domain,
\begin{align*}
(1)\quad
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{D_{\varepsilon}}f\,dx=\int_{\partial D}f\,d\sigma,
\end{align*}
where $D_{\varepsilon}=\{x \in \bar{D}:d(x,\partial D) \le \varepsilon\}$ and $\sigma$ is the surface measure on $\partial D$ ($(d-1)$-dim Hausdorff measure on $\partial D$)."

Since the author state this assertion without proof, **I want to know how to prove and generalize this assertion.**

**My attempt**

Let $D$ be a bounded domain on $\mathbb{R}^d$. That is, $D$ is a connected bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. We assume $m(\partial D)=0$ ($m$ is the $d$-dim Lebesgue measure).

- Define $F(x)=\inf_{y \in \partial D}|x-y|$.
  Note that $F$ is a Lipschitz continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $|\nabla F|=1$ $m$-a.e.
- Take $f \in L^{1}(\bar{D},m)$ and extend it on $\mathbb{R}^d$ by putting $f=0$ on $\mathbb{R^d}\setminus \bar{D}$.

Using coarea formula, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\{F=s\}}|f|\,d\sigma\,ds<\infty $ and
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{F>t\}}f\,dx=\int_{t}^{\infty}\left(\int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma \right)\,ds,\quad t \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\{0<F \le \varepsilon\}}f\,dx=\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{0}^{\varepsilon} \left(\int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma \right)\,ds.
\end{align*}
Since $f=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \bar{D}$, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{D_{\varepsilon}}f\,dx=\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{0}^{\varepsilon} \left(\int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma \right)\,ds.
\end{align*}

However, is $s \mapsto \int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma$ continuous?

**My question**

When is $s \mapsto \int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma$ continuous? Even if this is not true, under what conditions do we still have
$$
\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{0}^{\varepsilon} \left(\int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma \right)\,ds \to \int_{\{F=0\}}f\,d\sigma \, ?
$$
Even if $D$ is Lipschitz domain and $f$ is continuous, (1) must be valid.

Thanks for any information.

> **Information for (1)**
>
> Recently, I found an extension of (1) in this paper: [enter link
>   description here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5903.pdf). If you are interested, please look at Lemma 7.1
>   in this paper.

Comment: I see you have changed $C^2$ to $C^1$, in which case the result still holds (the volume formula is very robust) but you can no longer disintegrate the measure in a nice way. The set $\{F=s\}$ need not be $C^1$ and its $d-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure could be difficult to calculate/estimate (although I don't have specific examples). In other words I believe your method is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disintegration of the volume w.r.t. a surface measure
on $\Sigma_s=\{F=s\}\cap D$ and the parameter $s$ is difficult when 
$\Sigma_0=\partial D$ is only $C^1$. $\Sigma_s$ is in general only Lipschitz,
although with a Lipschitz constant that goes to 1 as $s\rightarrow 0$.
I guess there is still a well-defined surface measure on $\Sigma_s$
but I wouldn't know how to use it in calculations.
It is much easier to work directly with the volume form:

In the following, write $n_p$ for the unit vector, normal to the tangent space of $\Sigma_0$ at $p$  and 
pointing inwards in $D$.

First a geometric estimate:
For $\delta>0$ consider the quantity:
$$ \alpha(\delta) = \{ n_p \cdot v : 
p\in \Sigma_0, v \in T_q \Sigma_0, |v|=1, d(p,q)\leq \delta\}.$$
The dot-product is the cosine of the angle between the normal vector $n_p$ at $p$
 and a tangent vector  at $q$ when $p,q\in \Sigma_0$ are $\delta$-close.  $\alpha$ estimates
 the local 'flatness' of the surface.
We have $\alpha(0)=0$ and $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0} \alpha(\delta)=0$
because $\Sigma_0$ is assumed $C^1$ and compact.

Let $f$  be a continuous function with 
support in a small ball $B(p,\delta/2)$ around
$p\in \Sigma_0$. We will
show that for $\delta$ small 
 $$ \lim_{s\rightarrow 0 } \frac{1}{s} \int_{\{0\leq F \leq s\}\cap D} f\; d^d x =
    \int_{\Sigma_0} f\; d\sigma_0$$
 where $d\sigma_0$ is the area measure on the surface (well-defined as $\Sigma_0$ is $C^1$).
This suffices since for general $f$ 
you may use a partition of unity to reduce to this case.

Local coordinates:
Choosing $\delta>0$ small enough we may ensure that $B(p,\delta)\cap \Sigma_0$
is the (embedded) image of a $C^1$ map:
 $$ j : U \rightarrow \Sigma_0 \subset {\Bbb R}^d, \; 0\in U \subset {\Bbb R}^{d-1}, j(0)=p, $$
where $j'(u)$ is injective for all $u\in U$ and its image is the tangent space
of $\Sigma_0$ at $j(u)$. Write $n(u) = n_{j(u)}$ and
consider now the map:
  $$ \Phi(u,s) = j(u) + s n(u) , u\in U, s\in [0,\delta/2]$$

The Jacobian determinant, $J(u,s) = \det \Phi' =  \det ( j'(u) + s n'(u), n(u))$
is non-zero at $(u,s)=(0,0)$ and since continuous in
$u$ and $s$ we may by the inverse function theorem (possibly choosing $\delta$ 
smaller) assume that $\Phi$ is a bijection onto its image.
We then have an expression
for the volume element $d^d x = J(u,s) d^{d-1}u ds$ in local coordinates.
Furthermore, when restricted to $s=0$ it gives the $(d-1)$-dim area element on the surface
(because $n$ is a unit normal to the tangent space):
$$ d\sigma_0 = J(u,0) d^{d-1} u $$

The distance from $\Phi(u,s)$ to $\Sigma_0$ is clearly at most $s$ but a
geometric consideration (make a drawing) using the definition of $\alpha$ shows  that it is 
not smaller than $s \sqrt{1-\alpha(\delta)^2}$ (the last factor is an upper
bound for the sine of the angle between two normal vectors in $\Sigma_0\cap B(p,\delta)$).
It follows that for $0\leq s \leq \delta/2$ and restricting
to the set $B(p,\delta/2)$ we have
$$ \{x\in D: 0\leq F\leq s \sqrt{1-\alpha(\delta)^2}\} \subset \Phi(U,s)
\subset \{x\in D: 0\leq F\leq s\} . $$
Therefore,
$$ 
\frac{1}{s} \int_{0\leq F\leq s \sqrt{1-\alpha(\delta)^2} } f \; d^d x  \leq 
 \frac{1}{s}  \int_0^s \left( \int_U f(u,s) J(u,s) d^{d-1}u \right) ds \leq
\frac{1}{s}\int_{0\leq F\leq s} f \; d^d x 
$$
As $s\rightarrow 0^+$ the middle term goes to $\int_{\Sigma_0} f\; d\sigma_0$ by simple continuity,
and the outer terms (limsup and liminf)
agree within a factor $ \sqrt{1-\alpha(\delta)^2}$.
Patching things together we may
finally let $\delta$ go to zero and conclude since this
factor goes to one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but I couldn't understand what you are saying. How can I check the continuity of $s \mapsto \int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma$ using this diffeomorphism?

Comment: Details are somewhat lengthy to fill in, but in local coors, the Jacobian of the inverse of this diffeo gives the area form when on the surface and otherwise depends continuously upon $(x,s)$. Note that your function $F$ verifies $F(x+sn(x))=s$ for $s$ small so the coordinates I mention provide coordinates for $F=s$.

Comment: I'll think a little. By the way, is continuity of $f$ unnecessary for your solution?

Comment: Not sure. $L^1$ is not enough: Your problem is equivalent to the following situation: If $f$ is $L^1$ on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ then $\phi(x)=\int_0^1 f(x,t)dt$ exists a.e. and is $L^1$, but $\phi(0)$ need not exist nor equal $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_0^\epsilon \phi(x)dx$. You need conditions that these two quantities exist and are equal.

Comment: Thank you for your courteous reply. I think that I probably could understand that. I think the continuity of $f$ is necessary for proof.

Comment: You are welcome, and yes, I think it is difficult to get around continuity of $f$. On the other hand some kind of piecewise $C^1$ for $\partial D$ suffices. For example it works fine for a cube. Corners and edges give vanishing contributions to the limit.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh This is nice. Can something be said about the error term $\mathcal{E} = (1/\epsilon) \int_{D_{\epsilon}} f dx - \int_D f d\sigma$ ? is it possible to find a bound on $\mathcal{E}$ (possibly assuming more)? If yes I'll post a question

Comment: @lcv For $f$ continuous and $D$ being $C^1$, probably not much more to be said. But if $f$ is $C^k$ and $D$ is $C^{k+1}$, I think the error should be $C^k$ in $\epsilon$ (if this is the kind of result you are looking for ?).

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Oh yes sure. And in that case a bound on the error is essentially given by Taylor's theorem?

Comment: @lcv Yes, in principle. But probably rather hard to give explicit estimates. Under the hypotheses in my previous comment, the map $\Phi$ is going to be $C^k$ (for $\delta$ small) and you may develop as a Taylor series.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that  $ s \mapsto \int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma $ is indeed continuous. In a **tubular neighborhood** of $ \partial D $ there exists a bi-lipschitz maps between $\{F=s\}$ and $\{F=s'\}$ for $s$ and $s'$ near zero, and the bilipschitz constant approaches 1 as $s$ and $s'$ approach zero. Thus, their respective surface area element, or say their $d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}$, are $(1+\epsilon)$-close. As for the integrand, $f$ values on $\{F=s\}$ are uniformly close to $f$ values on $\{F=s'\}$ via the same bilipschitz correspondence, by continuity of $f$. So $\int_{\{F=s\}}f\,d\sigma$ must be very close to $\int_{\{F=s'\}}f\,d\sigma$.

All of this can be written quantitatively pretty easily. However, I tend to be a little wary of the $C^1$ boundary as opposed to $C^2$, b/c for instance a normal vector may not be continuous! So, might mess up the nice properties of a tubular neighborhood I have in mind!